# How to call and execute a shell script function parallelly over a while loop

Tags: bash, function, shell, parallel-processing, gnu

I have a shell script function as below. And I need to call this in a loop by passing different params. This function can be executed parallelly as each call to this function is independent. Can anyone help me achieve this?

```
process() {
  # Multiple POST calls using cURL command
}
```

This is the loop

```
while read -r line
do
  # Some more commands to extract params from like
  process "$param1" "$param2"
done <<< "$results"
```

I tried using wait, GNU parallel. But could not find the correct solution for this.

Comment: If you are sure that your system can handle the workload, then append a space and `&` to `"$param2"`.

Comment: This is something that _can_ be done with GNU parallel or with xargs; but if you don't show how you tried to use those tools, we can't say how they failed or how to avoid those failures. (There _are_ some extra tricks needed to run shell functions from a subprocess, but we have existing Q&A showing those tricks already).

Comment: (saying you tried to use `wait` doesn't make sense, because `wait` does the _opposite_ of putting content in the background: it makes the foreground stop until something running in the background finished; if you didn't start a background job as a child of the current shell, it doesn't do anything at all)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while read -r line
 do
  process "$param1" "$param2" &
done <<< "$results"
```